# Google Analytics compile Error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-firebase

I downloaded and compiled the analytics sample app from:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start

I downloaded and saved my configuratition file to:

```
app\google-services.json
```

When I build I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name
  'com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics'
```

**File: build.gradle (Project: analytics)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**File: build.gradle (Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'


    // [START gms_compile]
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    // [END gms_compile]
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What am I missing?

My goal is to run the sample app and see some activity appear on the Google Analytics web site when action is taken in the Android app.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This link looks relevant: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54